# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, frontend, react-apexcharts

I implemented a donut chart from react-apex chart and keep getting this error, whenever I render the page where the chart is located at. However once I change a property of the chart, the chart will be rendered without error in the frontend and is shown accordingly. Can anyone help me with this? My code looks like the following:

Chart.tsx

```
"use client";
import { ApexOptions } from "apexcharts";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const ReactApexChart = dynamic(() => import("react-apexcharts"), { ssr: false });

interface ChartThreeState {
    series: number[];
}

const options: ApexOptions = {
    chart: {
        type: "donut",
    },
    colors: ["#85b473f8", "#183d6df8"],
    labels: ["Verwendete Benefits", "Noch verfügbare Benefits"],
    legend: {
        show: true,
        position: "bottom",
    },

    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            donut: {
                size: "65%",
                background: "transparent",
            },
        }, 
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 2600,
            options: {
                chart: {
                    width: 380,
                },
            },
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 640,
            options: {
                chart: {
                    width: 200,
                },
            },
        },
    ],
};

const Chart: React.FC = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState<ChartThreeState>({
        series: [2, 0]
    });

    return (
        <div className="pt-4 col-span-12 ring-1 ring-secondary mx-0 rounded-lg border border-secondary bg-white px-5 pb-5 shadow-default sm:px-7.5 xl:col-span-6">
            <div className="mb-3 justify-between gap-4 sm:flex">
                <div>
                    <h5 className="text-xl font-semibold text-primary">
                        Nutzung
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="mb-2">
                <div id="chartThree" className="mx-auto flex justify-center">
                    <ReactApexChart
                        options={options}
                        series={state.series}
                        width={"100%"}
                        type="donut"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Chart;
```

Error Call Stack:

```
Call Stack
t.value
node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js (6:408535)
t.value
node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js (6:404268)
t.value
node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js (14:37170)
t.eval [as create]
node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js (6:4476)
eval
node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js (14:36561)
new Promise
<anonymous>
t.value
node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js (14:21686)
r.value
node_modules/react-apexcharts/dist/react-apexcharts.min.js (1:2575)
invokeLayoutEffectMountInDEV
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (23855:0)
invokeEffectsInDev
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26666:0)
legacyCommitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26646:0)
commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26630:0)
flushPassiveEffectsImpl
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26339:0)
flushPassiveEffects
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26263:0)
eval
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26000:0)
workLoop
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (261:0)
flushWork
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (230:0)
MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (534:0)
```

In the page itself I just render and import the component in the common way.
I tried multiple things even switching to different libraries, but I personally think that apexcharts looks the most promising when rendering the Chart.

Comment: `However once I change a property of the chart, the chart will be rendered without error in the frontend and is shown accordingly.` What property do you change and where do you change it ?

Comment: For example if I just change the color of the text within the h5 tag.

Comment: I am having exactly this same problem, the graph does not render and shows me the same error as you, and you are right when updating a value in the options object and saving the code, the graph renders without failure, but when reloading the browser the error reappears.

You still have not found the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but apparently the width and height attributes are required on the element.

So try adding the height in the attribute of your component.

```
<ReactApexChart
  options={options}
  series={state.series}
  width={"100%"}
  height={300}
  type="donut"
/>
```